# Any way to know how many rows are read by a select statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a large table containing some 15 million row, all varchar data. I ran a self join query on it which has a 3 self table join, something like this:

```
SELECT sj1.uid FROM tbl sj1 
JOIN tbl sj2 ON sj1.uid = sj2.uid 
JOIN tbl sj3 ON sj1.uid = sj3.uid
WHERE sj1.product_code = 'tb'
AND sj2.product_code = 'im'
AND sj3.product_code = 'mg'
```

Now it's been over 2 hours and when I check `show full processlist` I get status sending data and nothing else. I would like to know if there's any way to know how many rows have been processed by this query or any other relevant status. I can't even kill this query with a doubt that it might be nearing its end and if interrupted it will be a big waste of resource. Any help with this?

This is the what `EXPLAIN` explained me:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref                                    | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | ix_unique_user_id | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                                   | 14251264 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | ix_unique_user_id | ix_unique_user_id | 103     | ph_usertrack_analysis.a.unique_user_id |        2 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | ix_unique_user_id | ix_unique_user_id | 103     | ph_usertrack_analysis.a.unique_user_id |        2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+-------------+
```

So index on unique_user_id is being used

Comment: Have you indexed your tables recently?

Comment: Log slow queries and use EXPLAIN to help optimize them. EXPLAIN will also give row counts.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to know how many rows have been processed.

Comment: please see updated answer about what `EXPLAIN` explained me

Comment: So you're reading 15 million rows, that's quite a bit of data - no wonder it takes so long.

Comment: How dense are the records you actually care about? If only a small proportion of rows have the codes 'tb', 'im', and 'mg', you may be better off creating temporary tables with only the required records and joining those together.

Comment: no, every rows has a field with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get any information on query progress out of MySQL.

Comment: @Shades88: Yeah.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Answer (score -1):

[Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) you table with required column, See [Count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) also.

```
SELECT count(sj1.uid) FROM tbl sj1 
JOIN tbl sj2 ON sj1.uid = sj2.uid 
JOIN tbl sj3 ON sj1.uid = sj3.uid
WHERE sj1.product_code = 'tb'
AND sj2.product_code = 'im'
AND sj3.product_code = 'mg';
```

And Place [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) if needed.

Comment: What i understood, he needs row count his query will process acc to the given condition.

Comment: Yes, he can check the row count for his query which will process with the given `where` condition and later it can help him to get full data with the same condition. HE can get a thought about `how many rows will get processed` by his query.